# Notice: Undefined index when trying to increment an associative array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to increment the value for $variable each time a duplicate variable occurs. I'm not sure if this is syntactically correct, but I think this is semantically correct. var_dump seems to spit out the correct outputs, but i get this error: Notice: Undefined index...

```
$newarray = array();
foreach ($array as $variable)
{
    $newarray[$variable]++; 
    var_dump($newarray);
}
```

$array = (0 => h, 1 => e, 2 => l, 3=> l, 4=> o);

goal:

```
'h' => int 1
'e' => int 1
'l' => int 2
'o' => int 1
```

My code works, it's just that I get some weird NOTICE.

Comment: not a good practice and really don't know how much optimized this is considering the if performance but you could add @ in front of the operation like this @$newarray[$variable]++; and the notice will be supressed.. the bad part about this is that if you really have a problem in there it won't be displayed :)

Comment: the issue is fixed by adding an isset check

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$newarray = array();
foreach ($array as $variable)
{
    if (!isset($newarray[$variable])) {
        $newarray[$variable] = 0;
    }
    $newarray[$variable]++;
}
```

Comment: thanks! that isset did it. but i'm still trying to figure out why i needed that check?

Comment: the reason is because if the key does not exist in the array, add the key and set it to 0. gotcha.

Comment: Shouldnt it be "$newarray[$variable] = 1; " Otherwise, the first 'increment' will set to zero (and therefore not counted!)

Comment: Note that the answer has since been edited to be correct as-is.  It will set the value to 0 and then immediately increment it, so the 0 is never actually output.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the function [array_count_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php). It does exactly what you are trying to do.

Sample from php.net:

```
$array = array(1, "hello", 1, "world", "hello");
print_r(array_count_values($array));
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 2
    [hello] => 2
    [world] => 1
)
```

Answer (score 3):

In modern PHP, you can avoid the `isset()` call by leveraging the null coalescing operator.  In the snippet below, the technique sets the variable to 0 if the variable is not yet declared.  Then you can freely use a range of shorthand manipulations such as concatenation, arithmetic, etc.

```
$new = [];
foreach ($array as $v) {
    $new[$v] = ($new[$v] ?? 0) + 1;
}
```

Or if you want to continue using `++`, then you can use the "null coalescing assignment operator". The logic on the right side of assignment is not even executed if the variable is already declared. The below snippet will perform identically to the above snippet.

```
$new = [];
foreach ($array as $v) {
    $new[$v] ??= 0;
    ++$new[$v];
}
```

---

As for your sample data and desired result of letters and counts, I'd probably use a fully native, functional approach. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Q2aQq))

```
var_export(
    array_count_values(str_split('hello'))
); // letters are in the same order as they were encountered
```

Much less attractive technique for the same result:

```
$assoc = count_chars('hello', 1);
var_export(
    array_reduce(
        array_keys($assoc),
        fn($result, $k) => $result += [chr($k) => $assoc[$k]],
        []
    )
); // letters are alphabetized
```

Comment: I wish this was possible on one line without repeating the variable itself on the line. When collecting stats or numbers into a larger array, the variable declarations can become lengthy.

Comment: At this point, PHP does not have a "null coalescing addition assignment" operator.  That mythological beast might look like this: `??+=` or a "null coalescing incrementation `??++`. But then PHP would be going down a road of less human-readable sequences of symbols.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$newarray = array();
foreach ($array as $variable) {
    if ( !array_key_exists($variable, $newarray) ) {
        $newarray[$variable] = 0;
    }
    ++$newarray[$variable];
}
var_dump($newarray);
```

But you could also use [array_count_values()](http://docs.php.net/array_count_values) instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
$newarray = array();
foreach ($array as $variable)
{
    if(!isset($newarray[$variable]))
      $newarray[$variable] = 0;

      $newarray[$variable]++; 
    var_dump($newarray);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've gotten this figured out already. I was missing the isset check.

Answer (score 0):

I really like mickmackusa's use of null coalesce in

```
$new = [];
foreach ($array as $v) {
    $new[$v] ??= 0;
    ++$new[$v];
}
```

but you can save the second lookup using an array element reference which automatically inserts a `null` element if not present:

```
$new = [];
foreach ($array as $v) {
    $entry =& $new[$v];
    ++$entry;
}
```

Luckily, the increment operator considers `null` to be zero and increments to 1 as desired.

Answer (score 0):

This takes advantage of the fact that references accept undefined variables and PHP silently creates them:

```
$_ = &$lookup_with_long_name[$key_with_long_name] xor $_ += $value_with_long_name;
```

This only uses the lookup, key, and value variables once each, and sets if undefined and increments if defined, all without throwing a warning (or eventually an error in PHP 9)

xor operator works because PHP always has to evaluate both sides.

Make sure to unset($_) when you're done.

Answer (score -2):

You are incrementing the wrong thing, try this instead:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $variable) {
   $array[$key]++; 
   var_dump($array);
}
```

Comment: woops, i think it was a bit unclear from the previous code, I have updated it. not sure if that's still the issue though.