# How to select a Month AND year from mysql database using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, json

I am using the following script to retrieve all the invoices in a particular month / year.
The php pulls all the years and dates from the database, groups them together and puts them into a select menu, giving a result similar to :

```
June - 2013
July - 2013
August - 2013
September - 2013
```

This is the selectsummary.php :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Sales Summary</title>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jqueryui/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
       <link href="../js/select2/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/select2/select2.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() { $("select").select2(); });
        </script>

        <?php
    include '../connectmysqli.php';
    include '../menu.php';
         echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/template/template.css" />';
    $salesID = rand().rand();
    $today = date("Y-m-d");

    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#selectmonth').on('change', function (){

              // THIS IS WHERE I AM TRYING TO WORK OUT HOW TO RETRIEVE THE JSON AND THEN PLACE THE RESULTS INSIDE THE "summarycontent" DIV.     

                     $.getJSON('select.php', {monthyear: $(this).val()}, function(data){
                        var invoicerow = '';
                        for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
                            invoicerow += '<p>' + data[x]['invoiceID'] + '">' + data[x]['date'] + ' - ' + data[x]['grandtotal'] + ' - ' + data[x]['customerID'] + '</p>';
                        }
                        $('#summarycontent').html(invoicerow);
                      $("select").select2();
                    });

                    });     
                    });
            </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="addsalesubmit.php">
        <p>
          <select id="selectmonth">
            <option>Please Select A Monthly Summary To View</option>
            <?php

    $sql = <<<SQL
    SELECT YEAR(date) AS 'year', MONTHNAME(date) AS 'month'
    FROM `sales`
    GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTHNAME(date) DESC
    SQL;

    if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){ die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');}
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo '<option value="'.$row['month'].'-'.$row['year'].'">'.$row['month'].' - '.$row['year'].'</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
            ?>
            <br />
            <br />
        </form>
    <div id="summarycontent"></div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

This is the select.php which the ajax uses to lookup the results and send them back to the main script :

```
            <?php include '../connectmysqli.php'; ?>
    <?php
    $monthyear = strtotime($_GET['monthyear']);
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM sales WHERE date = ' . (int)$monthyear;
    $result = $db->query($sql);

    $json = array();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      $json[] = array(
        'invoiceID' => $row['invoiceID'],
        'date' => $row['date'],
        'grandtotal' => $row['grandtotal'],
        'customerID' => $row['customerID']
      );
    }
    echo json_encode($json);

    ?>
```

The problem I am having is im not sure how to convert the text such as 'July-2013' into something the select.php can use. As at the moment if I use chrome developer tools to see whats going on I get the following :

```
select.php?monthyear=July-2013
/manda/salessummary
```

So the date is going out ok, but im not sure how to then use it at the other end to select the dates in that month / year as its in the wrong format.

The database is as follows :

```
     id invoiceID   salesID customerID  vehicleID   date    comments    subtotal    vat grandtotal  description1    qty1T   linetotal1T stock1T stock2T description2    qty2T   linetotal2T stock3T description3    qty3T   linetotal3T stock4T description4    qty4T   linetotal4T stock5T description5    qty5T   linetotal5T discount
    68  1     1512428605    82428579    134722464   2013-07-08      22.48   4.50    26.98   Bridestone Pt34 - 175/55/18/W/63 - (99 In Stock) -...   1   22.48   711022407
```

EDIT >>>>

select.php now looks like this:

```
                    <?php include '../connectmysqli.php';

    $date_convert = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['monthyear']));
```

// Or, use LIST which would allow you to use the two date parts later.

list($month, $year) = explode('-', $_POST['monthyear']);

$SQL = "SELECT * FROM sales WHERE date = :date";
$STH = $db->prepare($SQL);
$STH->bindParam(':date', $date_convert);

```
    $json = array();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      $json[] = array(
        'invoiceID' => $row['invoiceID'],
        'date' => $row['date'],
        'grandtotal' => $row['grandtotal'],
        'customerID' => $row['customerID']
      );
    }
    echo json_encode($json);

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Use [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

Url: `select.php?monthyear=July-2013`

```
$date = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['monthyear']);

$mysql_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_GET['monthyear']));

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM sales WHERE date = ' . $mysql_date;
```

- P.S - Don't just concatenate parameters to the sql command. We're not in the 90's anymore.

A better option would be using `bind_param()`.

```
$mysql_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_GET['monthyear']));

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM sales WHERE date = ?';

$sql->bind_param("s", $mysql_date);
```

Comment: When I use the above I get : select.php?monthyear=August-2013
/manda/salessummary
GET
500
Internal Server Error
text/html
jquery.js:8526
Script
226 B
4 B
966 ms
954 ms
 

in console

Comment: this is in the developer console on chrome, I presume its coming from ajax, from the php select file

Comment: Iv just noticed that iv used your bottom PDO method, but im using mysqli to connect to the DB and using mysqli on everything else as I cant work out PDO.

Comment: All I get is this logged and nothing back : select.php?monthyear=August-2013
/manda/salessummary

Comment: Try and debug your PHP file. I can't help from here.

Answer (score 0):

**Convert Data**

```
$date_convert = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['monthyear']));

// Or, use LIST which would allow you to use the two date parts later.

list($month, $year) = explode('-', $_POST['monthyear']);
```

**Get Results**

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE date = :date";
$STH = $DBH->prepare($SQL);
$STH->bindParam(':date', $date_convert);
```

Comment: Im totally lost with PDO its like speaking spanish to me lol, I use mysqli

Comment: Thank!, im getting an error on this line in dreamweaver : $date_convert = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['monthyear']);

Comment: is it supposed to be  $date_convert = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['monthyear']));

Comment: On the server I get :
[12-Sep-2013 06:33:42 America/Denver] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: monthyear in /home3/websit52/public_html/manda/salessummary/select.php on line 3
[12-Sep-2013 06:33:42 America/Denver] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in /home3/websit52/public_html/manda/salessummary/select.php on line 7
[12-Sep-2013 06:33:42 America/Denver] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function bindParam() on a non-object in /home3/websit52/public_html/manda/salessummary/select.php on line 11

Comment: Iv just added the updated code above and now get : [12-Sep-2013 06:36:19 America/Denver] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: monthyear in /home3/websit52/public_html/manda/salessummary/select.php on line 3
[12-Sep-2013 06:36:19 America/Denver] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in /home3/websit52/public_html/manda/salessummary/select.php on line 7
[12-Sep-2013 06:36:19 America/Denver] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function bindParam() on a non-object in /home3/websit52/public_html/manda/salessummary/select.php on line 11

Comment: Ok, iv just edited my question with the latest version of select.php so you can see whats going on.

Comment: It looks like you have some issues with your array. Please see this question that fixes the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12040680/php-undefined-index-undefined-offset-work-arounds.

Answer (score 0):

After much playing around, this finally worked for the select.php :

```
    <?php 
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');

            include '../connectmysqli.php';

            list($month, $year) = explode('-', $_GET['monthyear']);

             $date = date_parse($month);
      $month = $date['month'];


    $sql = "SELECT * FROM sales WHERE MONTH(date) = '$month' AND YEAR(date) = '$year'";
    $result = $db->query($sql);

    $json = array();
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
              $json[] = array(
                'invoiceID' => $row['invoiceID'],
                'date' => $row['date'],
                'grandtotal' => $row['grandtotal'],
                'customerID' => $row['customerID']
              );
            }
            echo json_encode($json);

            ?>
```